# RecyclerView SnapHelper find the exact position of snapped item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I find the index of a snapped item?
I tried using:

```
recyclerView.setOnFlingListener(new RecyclerView.OnFlingListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(int velocityX, int velocityY) {
            Log.i(TAG, "initRecyclerView: SNAPPING TO:" +snapHelper.findTargetSnapPosition(recyclerView.getLayoutManager(),velocityX,velocityY)%songs.size());
            return false;
        }
    });
```

but it is really not accurate and sometimes it returns -1.

I tried :

```
snapHelper.findSnapView(recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
```

but it returns a view and I don't think I can get the index of a view inside recyclerview. (Am I wrong?)

I do not have a preference of when the method returns the index (before fling is finished or after).

ps: My recyclerview has a custom ZoomingLayoutManager (for carousel effect).
Maybe it's changing the view's size and that makes the snapHelper faulty? I know **snapHelper works on the average Height and Width of childViews visible**.

```
public class ZoomingLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    private final float mShrinkAmount = 0.5f;
    private final float mShrinkDistance = 0.9f;

    public ZoomingLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public int scrollHorizontallyBy(int dx, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int orientation = getOrientation();
        if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
            int scrolled = super.scrollHorizontallyBy(dx, recycler, state);

            float midpoint = getWidth() / 2.f;
            float d0 = 0.f;
            float d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint;
            float s0 = 1.f;
            float s1 = 1.f - mShrinkAmount;
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                float childMidpoint =
                        (getDecoratedRight(child) + getDecoratedLeft(child)) / 2.f;
                float d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint));
                float scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0);
                child.setScaleX(scale);
                child.setScaleY(scale);
            }
            return scrolled;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int scrollVerticallyBy(int dy, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int orientation = getOrientation();
        if (orientation == VERTICAL) {
            int scrolled = super.scrollVerticallyBy(dy, recycler, state);
            float midpoint = getHeight() / 2.f;
            float d0 = 0.f;
            float d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint;
            float s0 = 1.f;
            float s1 = 1.f - mShrinkAmount;
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                float childMidpoint =
                        (getDecoratedBottom(child) + getDecoratedTop(child)) / 2.f;
                float d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint));
                float scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0);
                child.setScaleX(scale);
                child.setScaleY(scale);
            }
            return scrolled;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

If it's true, how can I override the snapHelper methods to find the more exact position? Or am I just missing something obvious!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So thanks to Oğuzhan Döngül's tip I got the position figured out using `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` but there "when" you are calling the method is important.
When the scroll is finished, recyclerview's state changes to "idle", so thanks when you can use the method provided to get the exact position of first completely visible view.
but what if the position of the first visible view is not something that you want, and you want the position of the view in the middle of screen?

well, you can add offset, by calculating how many views are completely visible in the screen between the middle item and the screen border (its actually pretty simple)

so , the code:

```
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if(newState==RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
                int pos = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                if (pos >= 0) {
                    int position=pos+ bigScreenOffset;
                    // do your thing, the position value is the exact index of the middle item
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

where the `bigScreenOffset` is calculated by:

```
        bigScreenOffset= ( Utility.getDisplaySize(this,true,true)/200)/2;
```

and my custom method in my utility class that handles width|height in dp|px is :

```
 public static int getDisplaySize(Context context, boolean width, boolean dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    if (width) {
        if (dp)
            return (int) convertPixelsToDp(displayMetrics.widthPixels, context);
        else
            return displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    } else {
        if (dp)
            return (int) convertPixelsToDp(displayMetrics.heightPixels, context);
        else
            return displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this; in my case, only one item snapped at the center of the screen, left and right items are only partially visible and it works perfectly.

Add an `onScrollListener` and wait for the **SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING** state, then get the **FirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition**.

**NOTE:** I used a `Handler` with **1 second delay** as you see below, you can remove that part and only use `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()`. Used it for certainty of the scrolling state.

```
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                    int pos = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                    if (pos >= 0) {
                        // do your thing, the pos value must be your first fully visible or snapped view
                    }
                }, 1000);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        }
    });
```

Comment: If the user scrolls only 1 item it takes about half a second so it works and I can set the time to 500ms. but if the user scrolls three or more items, it takes - let's say- 2 secs! and It just returns the position of the next item. However, If I set the time to be for example 2000 ms, it delays if the user scrolls only one item